# Limited rotation towards mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, mouse-position

I have 2D game (unity, c# scripts), 
where is a submarine with ***tower*** *(parent)* and ***gun*** *(child)*.

[look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5StRJ.jpg)

- Tower can rotate (when I press A or D) around submarine body. (works fine)
- **Problem is** the gun on ***tower should rotate towards mouse***, but only in angle limitation. Angle limitation (by parent) now works fine, but gun doesn't look towards mouse.

```
    void Update() {
     Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

     mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

     Vector2 direction = new Vector2(mousePosition.x - 
     transform.localPosition.x,mousePosition.y - transform.localPosition.y);

     float angle = (Mathf.Atan2 (direction.y , direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);

     transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Min( 
     Mathf.Max( Mathf.Abs(angle),40 ),140 )));
    }
```

Here is a video where you can see how it "works" now: https://youtu.be/1pm54cjzYxA

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider Using LookAt(); function